# How can I show an element only if the page is not an article?

Tags: joomla

I have a code snippet in an override off the mod_breadcrumbs/default.php, in order to NOT show the last li element of the Breadcrumb when the view is an article.

The code is:

```
<?php if( JRequest::getVar( 'view' ) != 'article' ): ?>
        <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem" class="breadcrumb-item active"><?php echo $breadcrumbItem; ?>
            <meta itemprop="position" content="<?php echo $key + 1; ?>">
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Now with Joomla 4 the JRequest is creating the  error:

> Class "JRequest" not found

and we must use another code.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Riccardo contributes there too.  By posting all Joomla questions and advice in the niche community which was specifically created for such content, researchers will have an easier time finding what they need and receiving support.

Comment: If you are  willing to have this whole page migrated to JSE, please let me know and I'll set this in motion.  (we all have accounts there)

Answer (score 1):

JRequest was deprecated in Joomla 3 as well, in favour of JInput

```
$value = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('view');
```

input->get supports three params, only the first is required; full syntax is :

```
input->get('name','default','filter').
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the working solution is:

```
  <?php if( $app->getInput()->get('view') != 'article' ): ?>
```